# Including Bash autocompletion with setuptools

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, setuptools

I've got a couple packages in [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), and I'd like to include autocompletion features with both of them. How would you check that Bash autocompletion should be installed at all (check for `/etc/bash_completion`, maybe?), and how would you install it with setup.py (preferably using setuptools)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to require OS-level packages (i.e. `bash-completion`), then you should distribute your library as an OS-level package. That is, in `.deb`, `.rpm`, etc. Some tips here:

- [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/)
- [Fedora Packaging Guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging/Guidelines)

As part of the package generation, you can call your `setuptools` script to install the Python code. To ensure `bash-completion` is installed, you can specify it is a required package.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data_files` options:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
  ...
  data_files=[
      ('/etc/bash_completion.d/', ['extra/some_completion_script']),
    ]
)
```